# error in dired sorting on OS X

Tags: macos, emacs, dired

On OS X 10.5 Emacs 23.2, in dired-mode, if I try to sort by `dired-sort-toggle-or-edit` with prefix argument `--sort=extension` or `-X`, I get:

```
insert-directory: Listing directory failed but `access-file' worked
```

and the dired buffer becomes empty. I tried setting

```
(setq dired-use-ls-dired nil)
```

but this had no effect. `dired-sort-toggle-or-edit` and sorting by extension seems to work okay on my Ubuntu box. Anyone have a clue what's going on?

Comment: Thank you very much for creating such a useful question, which spawned answers and comments that lead to the solution.

Comment: Hmm.  I found this question by searching for the error I started getting on emacs startup: `ls does not support --dired; see `dired-use-ls-dired' for more details`.  So, I see/agree that a symlink isn't a great idea.  I have coreutils (thanks to Homebrew, IIRC) (including gls) installed already. So, the ls-lisp solution is intriguing, and I think the command @Marius lists _alone_ should work too.  I'm curious if @hatmatrix's solution has advantages.  Trying 'em...

Comment: Yup, Marius' works... let's see if I like the switches...   (yes, I intend to clean these comments up soon.)

Comment: I do not.  Advising folks to add a B to the value of dired-listing-switches seems like a terrible idea to me - if you don't TELL THEM what it does first!  And since dired colors such files grey already, hiding them seems like a not-great idea.  I went with `(setq dired-listing-switches "-al --human-readable --group-directories-first");`

Comment: Since gls works well, I'll skip ls-lisp - as I'm guessing the code of gls is better, and ls-lisp was built to handle situations where an ls wasn't available.  (If anyone wants me to clean up these 3 comments into 1 answer, please ping me.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `ls` that's installed on OS X doesn't support `-X` or any long arguments like `--sort`. Setting `dired-use-ls-dired` won't have any effect; dired will always use ls, but if that variable is non-nil, it will pass `--dired` to ls.

If you want that type of sorting, you can probably use something like fink to install coreutils, which will provide an ls more like what you're used to in Ubuntu.

Comment: Ah, so that's the problem... odd that FreeBSD wouldn't have that type of sorting. And I thought fink was dead but actually looks active... wonder why I'd thought that. Thanks.

Comment: I installed `coreutils` through Homebrew, and it apparently installs `/usr/local/bin/gls`. I `ln -s`'d this to `/usr/local/bin/ls` and then I didn't get the error in Emacs any more.

Comment: @duma: This did not work for me under Yosemite 10.10.3. I then used, additionally, `(setq insert-directory-program "/usr/local/bin/gls"); use proper GNU ls` in `.emacs` and it worked

Answer (score 18):

For now, I've also found another solution using `ls-lisp`

```
(when (eq system-type 'darwin)
  (require 'ls-lisp)
  (setq ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program nil))
```

Comment: You can also use eshell, whose builtin ls understands -X.

Comment: Is it possible to set `insert-directory-program` as eshell's `ls`?

Comment: thanks @crippledlambda I combined this answer and duma's comment on the previous one to set my insert-directory-program to gls and everything works for me now on mac OSX

Comment: This saved me a lot of headache. I'm actually on windows PowerShell, using cygwin emacs, but same exact issue. `ls` won't accept any "long" args. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 9):

Here are the steps for Emacs running on Snow Leopard 10.6.8 using `coreutils` installed through macports:

NOTE:   My macports installation is different than the generic (`/opt/...`) -- i.e., I use `/macports` as the root.  Altering the root setup is not required, it is just a personal preference of mine.  For vanilla macport installations or alternative setups, adjust the path accordingly.

```
sudo /macports/bin/port install coreutils
```

This goes inside the `.emacs` or `init.el`:

```
;; sort directories first

(setq insert-directory-program "/macports/bin/gls")

(setq dired-listing-switches "-aBhl --group-directories-first")
```

NOTE:   Using a symlink for `gls`/`ls` is *not* recommended because it breaks functionality with macports install and most likely other stuff too.

---

Alternative installation for users who want more control:

Download:  `coreutils-8.21.tar.xz` from:  http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/

If you do not have a utility to unzip an `*.xz` file, you can use a utility such as `TheUnarchiver3.9.1`.

Here is a quick reference to make the `coreutils` -- I set the installation location to my own personal preference instead of the default:

```
./configure \
--prefix=/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/elpa

make

sudo make install
```

Insert these into your `.emacs` or `init.el` file -- adjust the path accordingly:

```
;; sort directories first

(setq insert-directory-program "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/elpa/bin/ls")

(setq dired-listing-switches "-aBhl --group-directories-first")
```

Answer (score 7):

Still happening in 2020! If, like me, you're using **brew** as your open source package manager, and you have already installed coreutils with `brew install coreutils`, this is the right solution to copy paste in your `.emacs` file, or wherever you keep your startup customizations:

```
(when (equal system-type 'darwin)
  (setq insert-directory-program "/insert/here/path/to/homebrew/ls"))
```

(I check for the OS because I deploy my Emacs configuration on multiple systems).

Current path:

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/ls
```

Previously (before 2022?) it used to be:

```
/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/ls
```

As usual, if you have configured gnu ls as your default in your current shell of choice, you can always check its current full path by typing `which ls`.

Oddly enough, this happened suddenly on a Mojave system on which I routinely use Emacs since forever, and on which I am sure dired was working in the past. I guess that an update broke something that made dired use the correct binary, without having to manually set it.

Comment: For anyone following this answer, you also need to install coreutils (through brew) for this to work. This can be done with the command `brew install coreutils`.

Comment: homebrew changed it's default path. The path to coreutils ls is now `/opt/homebrew/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/ls`

Answer (score 0):

This is not much different than lawlist's nice answer, but has slightly different information and is tailored to those who use the Nix package manager:

```
(use-package dired
  :custom
  ;; See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115465/emacs-dired-too-much-information
  ;; NOTE: Just some information worth keeping in mind. More readable dired file
  ;; size output - consider adding F (make file type obvious), or p (p adds a
  ;; trailing slash to dirs, but makes moving dirs fail), and G (colorize) too.
  (dired-listing-switches "-alh --group-directories-first")
  :config
  ;; [[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076360/error-in-dired-sorting-on-os-x][macos - error in dired sorting on OS X - Stack Overflow]]
  ;; To fix the
  ;; (error "Listing directory failed but 'access-file' worked")
  ;; error. Emacs needs to use gnu's ls, which I get through nixpkgs' coreutils.
  ;; In my config, currently, Emacs is not picking up the path to my nix install
  ;; ls (todo: fix).
  ;;
  ;; Note that, unlike the info at the link provided above,
  ;; --group-directories-first is not needed to fix this error. I just like to
  ;; see the directories first in a dired buffer.
  (setq insert-directory-program (expand-file-name ".nix-profile/bin/ls"
                                                   (getenv "HOME"))))
```