# Error in Dired sorting on Windows (with Cygwin Emacs)

Tags: windows, emacs, cygwin, dired

In a Cygwin Emacs on Windows, in Dired, if I try to sort by time (for example), I get the error:

```
insert-directory: Listing directory failed but `access-file' worked
```

In a Windows Emacs binary on Windows, I do not have any problem, but Emacs uses its own implementation of `ls` IIUC.

What I don't understand is that Cygwin `ls` DOES understand options such as `--dired` and `-t` (to sort by modification time).

My current config:

```
;; Switches passed to `ls' for Dired.
(setq dired-listing-switches
      (cond ((eq system-type 'windows-nt) ; Native Windows version of Emacs.
             "-a -F -l")
            (t                            ; Cygwin version of Emacs or ...
             "-a -F --group-directories-first -l --time-style=long-iso")))
```

Comment: The underlying issue appears to be related to a thread entitled **error in dired sorting on OS X**:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/4076360/2112489  I do not know whether Cygwin can be configured to use `coreutils`, which supports the `--group-directories-first` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `dired-listing-switches` to `"-aFl"` instead of `"-a -F -l"`. Maybe that will make some difference (but it does not change anything for me).

What is your value of `ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program`? If it is non-`nil` try setting it to `nil`, so that you use ls-lisp instead of Cygwin's `ls`. (At least do that as a trial, and maybe you will want to stick with that.)

what is your value of option `ls-lisp-emulation`? If it is something else, try customizing it to `MS-Windows`. (Be sure to read `C-h v` for this option - e.g., use Customize.)

In sum, I suggest that you first try getting Dired to work OK using ls-lisp and not Cygwin's `ls`. That will at least give you a solid Dired to work with. If you like, you can then still pursue tackling your problem as stated, i.e., to get it working with Cygwin Emacs.

Comment: The `"-a -F -l"`string is for the Windows Emacs case, and Dired sorting works OK in that version of Emacs.

Comment: Now, I tried to remove options from the second string, the one for all other versions of Emacs, and Dired sorting works OK when I remove `"--time-style=long-iso"`. But, then, I don't have the dates in the format I'm wishing...

Comment: The variable `ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program` was undefined before explicitly requiring `ls-lisp`. After `(setq ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program nil) (require 'ls-lisp)`, its value is now `t`.

Comment: Though, when using ls-lisp, I have weird extra columns at the beginning of the Dired buffer. See http://screencast.com/t/iZlDIKlzy8.

Comment: `"-aFl"` works fine in the Windows Emacs case, as does Dired sorting. No need to use `"-a -F -l"`. Dunno if using the latter is part of your problem, but there is no need for it.

Comment: If the Emacs or the `ls` you are using does not support a given switch, such as `"--time-style-long-iso"`, then it won't have any effect (and at worst it might cause problems). Nothing to be done about that. Don't use that switch when you use that Emacs or that `ls`.

Comment: Wrt your screencast: You don't say what switches you used. Try changing the switches slightly, to see what is adding those columns. I don't see such columns, e.g., with `-alF`. The second of the columns you show could be from switch `-s` - it is normal for `-s` to add the block size at that location.

Comment: Regarding `"-aFl"`vs `"-a -F -l"`, it simply that I've always written one-letter flags so. It's not done for a particular reason other than habit.  Is your shorter version better in some cases?

Comment: Regarding the `--time-style=long-iso`option, it is supported by the Cygwin `ls`; it does work from the Cygwin terminal. That's what I do not understand... why doesn't it work when called from Dired (in Cygwin Emacs)?

Comment: Regarding the screenshot, it's when I used `ls-lisp`: when I do eval `(setq ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program nil) (require 'ls-lisp)`. The value of `dired-listing-switches` at that moment is: Its value is `"-a -F --group-directories-first -l"`.

Comment: Try getting rid of `--group-directories-first`? When I add that switch I see what you see. Presumably ls-lisp does not support that switch. Should be no difference between `-alF` and `-a -l -F` (and I notice none), but who knows?

Comment: Using just `-alF` or `-a -l -F` with `ls-lisp` now works OK in Cygwin Emacs. So problem solved. However, I still don't get it why using the Cygwin `ls` command does not work from Cygwin Emacs... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it works. Dunno why Cygwin `ls` apparently doesn't work. Maybe someone will ultimately offer some help in that regard.

Comment: I'd like it to work. But, at the end, that's the result which imports me most. Thanks for your help on working around the problem.

Comment: BTW, in the same vein, `find-name-dired` is behaving differently between Windows Emacs and Cygwin Emacs: `find . \( -iname emacs\* \) -exec ls -ld \{\} \;` in the first case (for searching "emacs*") and `find . \( -iname emacs\* \) -ls` in the second one, leading to extra weird columns before the perms. Any idea?

Comment: @user3341592 Check the path that emacs is using to find ls ... it's probably not cygwin's /bin/ls. You can always explicitly set  insert-directory-program  to the path of the correct ls.

Comment: @user3341592 Those "weird extra columns" are the inode number (ls -i) and block count (ls -s). Perhaps ls-lisp is interpreting --group-directories-first as a bunch of  single-letter flags.